# KnockoutJS Foreach containing Options binding not updating the ViewModel

Tags: jquery, data-binding, foreach, knockout.js

I am trying to use a nested `options`, (`optionsText`, `optionsValue`) and `value` binding inside a `foreach` binding in KO.

I expected the following code to bind the select box to the ViewModel's related `Item` but it doesn't appear to be updating the values in the view model - they always stay as the value I initialised them with "n/a" - how can I do that?

I have set up a html page as follows:

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: Items">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: $parent.Countries, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Code', value: 'Country'"></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind="text: Country"></span>                    
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <a href="#" data-bind="click: AddItem">Add item</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
var countries = ko.observableArray([
    { Name : "United Kingdom", Code : "UK", Population : "1 Monarch" },
    { Name : "Australia", Code : "AU", Population : "22 million kangaroos" },
    { Name : "Antarctica", Code : "AQ", Population : "100,000 penguins (0 polar bears)" }
]);

var item = { Country : "n/a" };

var ViewModel = function() {
    this.Countries = countries;

    this.Items = ko.observableArray();
    this.AddItem = function() {
        this.Items.push(ko.mapping.fromJS(item));
    };
};
var vm = new ViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UCAxs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove quotes from `value` binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.Countries, 
                   optionsText: 'Name', 
                   optionsValue: 'Code', 
                   value: Country"></select>
```

Here is working fiddle:
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/UCAxs/1/)

Comment: Thanks - that was the problem. Fiddly!